# The sequence of executed statements of a Java program

Tags: java, code-coverage, execution

Given a Java program, I would like to run it and determine the sequence of statements that were executed. For instance, upon running the program

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  // line 4
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int m = n;
        if (n > 0) {
            m = 2 * n;
        } else {
            m = 3 * n;
        }
    }
}
```

using a negative integer as the input, I would like to obtain the sequence 4, 5, 6, 7, 10 (perhaps without the 7), referring to the lines that were executed.

Of course, one can always add a System.out.println after every statement in the source code, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: Hint: you can determine it by n value before executing code.

Comment: why do you want to do that? If it's for debugging purpose, some well-placed logs and eventually a single stacktrace should be enough.

Comment: Are you referring to a literal _"[statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)"_, or just an _"expression"_?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! Actually, the problem can be solved by adding a System.out.println after every semicolon, since I only really need to keep track of simple statements. I've just been wondering whether there is a more elegant way, e.g., by having the JVM "remember" the instructions that it actually executed and using the correspondence between the source code statements and the JVM instructions (this correspondence must exist -- how else would the JVM know which line in the source code threw an exception?) to make the list of the source code statements that were executed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will work like that. You'd definitely have to use a `System.out` for every line that get's executed, although you can first collect these line numbers in a `List` and then display them at the end.

If you really intend to get the line numbers automatically you have to grab a stacktrace

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()
```

This will give you the line number you're currently on (which is obviously the number of that exact statement). If you want you can also move that to a separate function and then move up the stacktrace to get the line number.

However you **really really** should not do that. Grabbing a stacktrace is one of the most expensive operations in Java. You really don't want to do this for every statement that you execute unless performance is of absolutely  no value to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach the requested effect by **Code Coverage**.

1. Call the code from within a [JUnit test](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/).
2. Run the code from an IDE as "run test with coverage". Most probably you will have to install some "test coverage" plugin to your IDE.
3. You will see all the lines which ran marked with green directly in your IDE.

For example for IntelliJ IDEA, the plugin is called "Code Coverage":

[image]

and you run it like this:

[image]

Then you see the result in the IDE in the "coverage" Window:

[image]

and after clicking on the class name notice the green and red "marker" on the left:

[image]